# Write value of several cells not in a row to array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know how to create a range to get values from cells and add to an array.  I am having issues adding values from several cells that are not in sequence (1,1,10,1).

I am trying to get add the values like this

```
  var Array = [
    sheet.getRange("AD3").getValue(),
    sheet.getRange("AG3").getValue(),
    sheet.getRange("AJ3").getValue(),
    sheet.getRange("AM3").getValue(),
    sheet.getRange("AD23").getValue(),
    sheet.getRange("AG23").getValue(),
    sheet.getRange("AJ23").getValue(),
    sheet.getRange("AM23").getValue(),
  ]
```

Its not working, each return "undefined".  They are dates in those cells. Here's how I tested:

```
for (var i=0; i < Array.length; i++) {
     if (Array[i][0] != ""){ 
        Logger.log(Array[i][0])
    }
}
```

Any help would be apricated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I think that when those cells are the value and the empty, `getValue()` returns the value and `""`, respectively. So I cannot understand the situation for returning `undefined` from `getValue()`. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for replicating for returning `undefined` from `getValue()`? For example, `each return "undefined"` means that the cell value is `undefined`?

Comment: There is not much more detail to give.  Each of those cells has data in them, dates.  I would like to add those date to an array.

I have just a test script written with the above and following to test getting the data.  Apologies, I cannot format to code

  for (var i=0; i < Array.length; i++) {    
    if (Array[i][0] != ""){
      Logger.log(Array[i][0])

    }
  }

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your repling in the comment, I understood your issue is from the following script.

```
var Array = [
  sheet.getRange("AD3").getValue(),
  sheet.getRange("AG3").getValue(),
  sheet.getRange("AJ3").getValue(),
  sheet.getRange("AM3").getValue(),
  sheet.getRange("AD23").getValue(),
  sheet.getRange("AG23").getValue(),
  sheet.getRange("AJ23").getValue(),
  sheet.getRange("AM23").getValue(),
];
for (var i=0; i < Array.length; i++) {
  if (Array[i][0] != ""){
    Logger.log(Array[i][0])
  }
}
```

In your value of `Array` is 1 dimensional array. So, when you use this script, the top letter of each element is retrieved. In this situation, when each value is the date object, `null` is returned. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

When you want to see each value from `Array` using your additional script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your for loop is modified.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
  if (Array[i].toString() != "") {
    Logger.log(Array[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using RangeList Class:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["AD3","AG3","AJ3","AM3","AD23","AG23","AJ23","AM23"]);
  let vals = []
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(r => {
    vals.push({loc: r.getA1Notation(),value: r.getValue()})
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vals))
}
```

[RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

```
Execution log
11:16:15 AM Notice  Execution started
11:16:17 AM Info    [{"loc":"AD3","value":""},{"loc":"AG3","value":""},{"loc":"AJ3","value":""},{"loc":"AM3","value":""},{"loc":"AD23","value":""},{"loc":"AG23","value":""},{"loc":"AJ23","value":""},{"loc":"AM23","value":""}]
11:16:17 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Obviously my values will not agree with yours since I don't have your data